# How to reorder this array in a specific order?

Tags: php

I have this string of random numbers that needs to have some of the integers converted into letters. Notice that it takes two positions in the string to make a letter.

```
01110413 Original string
```

This string should ultimately be converted into this:

```
A11D13   Converted string
```

Here is my code so far

```
$id  = '01110413';

$chg = array(0 => array(0, 1), 3 => array(4, 5));
$ltr = array(00 => 'A', 01 => 'B', 03 => 'C', 04 => 'D');

$id = str_split($id);

foreach($chg as $ltrpos => $val){

    // $ltrpos; letter position placement in string AFTER conversion to letter

    $ltrkey = null;

    foreach($val as $idkey){
        $ltrkey .= $id[$idkey];
        unset($id[$idkey]);

        if(!empty($ltrkey)){
          $out[$ltrpos] = $ltr[(INT)$ltrkey];
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [3] => D
)
```

I need to insert these new values in the place where the old integer values were. **The `$chg` array key is the position where the values should be in the converted string.**

How can I order my final `$out` array so that the integers that were unset are replaced with the converted letters in their place?

Comment: _“The $chg array key is the position where the values should be in the converted string”_ – no idea what that’s supposed to mean, resp. how it applies to the minimal example given.

Comment: Look at the post. I give an example: `A11D13   Converted string`. See positions `0` and `3`?

Comment: _“I need to insert these new values in the place where the old integer values were”_ – also unclear – haven’t you replaced the integers before already? `B` isn’t even in your final result that you given upfront, and `D` is there because `04` was replaced by it already, not?

Comment: _“See positions 0 and 3?”_ – yeah, so? Still doesn”t explain _why_ `A` ends up as the first character of the result.

Comment: Couldn't you do it [like this](http://3v4l.org/bQaOW)?

Comment: _“Notice that it takes two positions in the string to make a letter”_ – aha. And _which ones_?

Comment: And therein lays my issue. I need to reorder the results.

Comment: @kingkero, I'm looking at this now. It looks a whole lot better than what I have

Comment: @kingkero, Can you please post your answer below so I can give you credit? Thank you for your help

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of your previous question, [Mapping array values to another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648295/mapping-array-values-to-another-array)

Comment: @CBroe, Yeah, nobody had a clue there so I completed what functionality I could and re posted it

Comment: _“nobody had a clue”_ – pretty bold statement, given how much _your_ description of what is actually to be achieved lacks in comprehensibility! And anyway, you should have updated your original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for the next time. Instead of spouting off, why couldn't you come up with a solution like kingkero? This is a help forum, no?

Comment: @NaN So I posted the answer here and I think you can delete the other question

Comment: _“why couldn't you come up with a solution”_ – because you did not even explain what you want to achieve properly – how many times does that need repeating before you get it? (And no, that a few people might have _guessed_ right what you _might_ want is not credit to your problem description.)

Comment: _“This is a help forum, no?”_ – yes; and the ability to _solve_ a problem goes along very much with being able to properly _describe_ the problem first. And seeing how you struggle with the latter it is no surprise you can’t manage the former either. So _trying_ to get you to describe the problem better _is_ actually helping you(whether you might be able to see that right now already or not).

Comment: @CBroe, there is no need to attack here. I'm sorry that you were not able to follow my clear instructions above. It couldn't be simpler. Yes, I was on the wrong track but kingkero was able, without issue or question to **comprehend** what I was asking and provided a crystal clear solution. Because you couldn't figure it out doesn't entitle you you to become angry

Comment: Yeah, comments by yourself under that answer like _“If I'm not mistaken, I think this may be what I'm after”_ make it clear how much thought-through this already is … LOL

Comment: Why couldn't you see the original string and the converted string come up with a solution? That was why I posted it waaay up top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$id  = '01110413';

// your string codes always take up two positions, so you just need to provide the final position in the string
$chg = array(0,3);
// You could actually change 00 to just 0 (since they're integers).  Also, later in the script, the two character position is cast to an int, so it will match these values.
$ltr = array(00 => 'A', 01 => 'B', 03 => 'C', 04 => 'D');

$converted_id = doConvert($id, $ltr, $chg);

function doConvert($id, $conversion_codes, $final_position) {
    if( count($final_position) == 0 ) return $id;

    $next_pos = array_shift($final_position);

    // convert the two characters at the next position to a letter
    $id = substr($id, 0, $next_pos) . $conversion_codes[(int) substr($id, $next_pos, 2)] . substr($id, $next_pos+2); // (cast to an (int) so it will match the keys in our conversion array)

    return doConvert($id, $conversion_codes, $final_position);
}
```

Output of this example is:

```
B11D13
```

You say the first value should be `A`, but `01 => B`, that's why the first letter is `B`.

Comment: Thanks Cully. I'm still looking at kingkeros solution.

Comment: Cully, I tried this and it seems to be what I am after so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If every two characters in your original id is a code, you can use something more general, like this:

```
$id  = '01110413';

$conversion = array('00' => 'A', '01' => 'B', '03' => 'C', '04' => 'D');

$converted_id = "";
for($i=0; $i < strlen($id); $i+=2) {
    $char_code = substr($id, $i, 2);
    // we don't know this code, just append it
    if( empty($conversion[$char_code]) ) {
        $converted_id .= $char_code;
    }
    // convert and append
    else {
        $converted_id .= $conversion[$char_code];
    }
}
```